# how to use Ansible variables correctly?

Tags: ansible

```
- name: Create Dirs for rs disk
  file:
    name: "{{ /rs{{ items }}"
    state: directory
  with_sequence: start=1 end={{ disk_group[inventory_hostname]['rs'] | length }}
  when: disk_group[inventory_hostname]['rs'] is defined
```

[tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UcMz.jpg)

When "when" clause is false, how to avoid errors that vairable is undefined in "with_sequence".

In fact, use ignore_errors can do that, but I do think it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this example of *include_tasks*

```
> cat task.yml
  - debug: var=item
    with_sequence: start=1 end={{ rs|length }}

> cat playbook.yml
  - hosts: localhost
    vars:
  #    rs: test
    tasks:
      - include_tasks: task.yml
        when: rs is defined
```

Comment: Good idea, you give me great help, Thanks.